# Java 7 try-with-resources - what can be in try clause

Tags: java, try-catch

I know that there must be a variable declaration associated with the resource in the try clause.

But as well being assigned a usual resource instantiation, could it instead be assigned an already existing resource eg :

```
public String getAsString(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {   
    try (BufferedReader in = request.getReader(); ){ 
        etc 
    } 
}
```

ie. will the `BufferedReader` be closed automatically just like resources instantiated directly in the try clause ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - if you declare a closeable resource in the try block (where you wrote "etc"), it ***won't*** be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can test whether this is true using this code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
        AutoCloseable _close = getCloseable()
       try (AutoCloseable close = _close) {
           // ...
       }

    }

    public static AutoCloseable getCloseable() {
        return new MyCloseable();
    }
}

class MyCloseable implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Closing");
    }
}
```

The output is "Closing". This means that indeed, `AutoCloseable`s that are created before the `try` block will still be closed after the `try` block.

Actually, Java does not care what you put in the `()` of the `try` block, as long as it implements `AutoCloseable`. At runtime, the expression will be automatically evaluated to a value, whether it is a `new` expression or not.

Comment: @AndyThomas What does "already existed" even mean? I thought it meant that it meant "anything not instantiated in the `()`" judging from context.

Comment: @AndyThomas Edited.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**. Anything that is `AutoCloseable` will call the `close` method. try-with-resource will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `BufferedReader` will be closed automatically.

Since Java 7, Interface `AutoCloseable` is added as a SuperInterface of `Closeable`, so all implementing classes of `Closeable` (ie. Resource classes) interface automatically inherit `AutoCloseable` interface.